R separate_longer_delim to split strings with quotation marks
I am trying to use the separate_longer_delim() function from the tidyr package to split a string into separate rows.
This is how the dataset looks like:



Subject
Outcome




001
["Rubbing of nose or ears","Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat","Mild pain","Eye itching"]


002
["Itchy Tongue", Mild pain","Eye irritation"]



And I would like the dataset to be:



Subject
Outcome




001
Rubbing of nose or ears


001
Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat


001
Mild pain


002
Itchy Tongue


002
Mild pain


002
Eye irritation



Code for data:
subject <- c('001', '002')
outcome <- c('["Rubbing of nose or ears","Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat","Mild pain","Eye itching"]', '["Itchy Tongue", Mild pain","Eye irritation"]')

dta <- as.data.frame(cbind(subject, outcome))


library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

dta |>
  mutate(outcome = str_replace_all(outcome, '\",', "&") |> str_remove_all("[^[\\w,& ]+]")) |>
  separate_longer_delim(outcome, "&")

This replaces ", with a new delimiter & since end quote + a comma delimits the elements of outcome. We can then split on this new delimiter.
Alternatively, you can split on ", and then remove everything that is not a a word character, comma, or space:
dta |>
  separate_longer_delim(outcome, '\",') |>
  mutate(outcome = str_remove_all(outcome, "[^[\\w ,]+]"))

Output
  subject                              outcome
1     001              Rubbing of nose or ears
2     001 Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat
3     001                            Mild pain
4     001                          Eye itching
5     002                         Itchy Tongue
6     002                            Mild pain
7     002                       Eye irritation


You can try reticulate::py_eval
library(reticulate)
dta %>%
  mutate(outcome = map(outcome, py_eval)) %>%
  unnest(outcome)

which gives
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  subject outcome
  <chr>   <chr>
1 001     Rubbing of nose or ears
2 001     Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat
3 001     Mild pain
4 001     Eye itching
5 002     Itchy Tongue
6 002     Mild pain
7 002     Eye irritation


py_eval() was the function I could not remember from reticulate! Very succinct.

Something like:
subject <- c('001', '002') 
outcome <- c('["Rubbing of nose or ears","Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat","Mild pain","Eye itching"]', '["Itchy Tongue","Mild pain","Eye irritation"]')

dta <- as.data.frame(cbind(subject, outcome))

dta |>
  tidyr::separate_longer_delim(cols = "outcome", delim = "\",\"") |>
  dplyr::mutate(outcome = stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(outcome, pattern = "\\[\"|\"\\]", replacement = ""))
#>   subject                              outcome
#> 1     001              Rubbing of nose or ears
#> 2     001 Itching of the mouth, tongue, throat
#> 3     001                            Mild pain
#> 4     001                          Eye itching
#> 5     002                         Itchy Tongue
#> 6     002                            Mild pain
#> 7     002                       Eye irritation

Created on 2024-08-01 with reprex v2.1.0
